# Generating dependency files in separate folder

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to create a makefile for a project with the following structure:

```
├──bin/
├──build/
│  ├──foo.d
│  └──bar.d
├──include/
│  └──foo.h
│
├──lib/
├──src/
│  ├──foo.cc
│  └──bar.cc
│
├──Makefile
```

Here is the makefile:

```
# Define the compiler and the linker.
CXX = g++
CC  = g++
# Folders
srcdir   = src
builddir = build
out      = bin

# Define preprocessor, compiler, and linker flags.
CPPFLAGS  = -I include -std=c++11
LDFLAGS   = -g -Llib

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all clean test

# Targets
all : $(out)/bar
$(out)/bar : $(addprefix $(builddir)/,bar.o foo.o)

# Standard clean
clean :
    rm -f $(builddir)/*.o $(builddir)/*.d

# Generate dependencies in *.d files
$(builddir)/%.d: $(srcdir)/%.cc
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
     $(CPP) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
     sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,$(builddir)/\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
     rm -f $@.$$$$;

deps = $(patsubst $(srcdir)/%.cc,$(builddir)/%.d,$(wildcard $(srcdir)/*.cc))
include $(deps)
```

The dependency files contain the following:

foo.d

```
build/foo.o build/foo.d : src/foo.cc include/foo.h
```

bar.d (depends on foo)

```
build/bar.o build/bar.d : src/bar.cc include/foo.h
```

Is there any way to generate the .d files in the build/ directory, compile the object files into the very same folder then compile the bin/bar program? Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

The problem was that I was expecting

```
all : $(out)/foo

$(out)/foo : $(addprefix $(builddir)/,foo.o bar.o)

$(builddir)/%.o : $(srcdir)/%.cc
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ -MP -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d)
```

to magically compile the program foo (it works when all files are in the same folder).

Instead I had to specify the recipe:

```
all : $(out)/foo

$(out)/foo : $(builddir)/foo.o $(builddir)/bar.o
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(builddir)/%.o : $(srcdir)/%.cc
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ -MP -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d)
```

Comment: Do note that the dependency rules are a convenience for project developers, not an actual build requirement.  If you just want to go from a bare source distribution to a binary as quickly and easily as possible, then avoid generating the dependency rules.  Under those circumstances, you know you need to build everything anyway.

Comment: With respect to the question as posed, however, it's unclear to me what you're asking.  How to generate the `.d` files in the `build` directory instead of elsewhere?  How to write make rules that will allow all the steps you described to be triggered by one `make` run?  Something else?

Comment: I updated the question for clarity. The actual project I'm trying to write the makefile for has tons of files. The makefile while using one folder was really clean and efficient. I am simply trying to keep the automatic generation of dependencies while migrating to a decent project folder structure.

Comment: Ok, but what's the problem you are facing with the `Makefile` you presented?  What is the actual question?

Comment: I wish I had enough points to upvote your response. There wasn't really anything wrong with my makefile, rather a misunderstanding of what I thought it would accomplish. With all files in one folder make was automatically running a recipe for generating the program, but with several folders I had to define it on my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop all of the `sed` nonsense. gcc can generate everything in one go:

```
$(builddir)/%.o : $(srcdir)/%.cc
    $(CPP) -c $< -o $@ -MP -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d)
```

That will in one go build `build/foo.o` and `build/foo.d`, where `build/foo.d` will have the autogenerated dependencies for `build/foo.o`.

Comment: For some reason this gives me 
`foo.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @SebastianN in what context?

Comment: I was mistaken when I thought my issue was dependency generation related, it was just a newbie mistake when it came to defining recipes. The error I posted above was because I used `$(CPP)` instead of `$(CXX)` in my recipe.

Thank you for providing this much cleaner version of dependency generation than the sed-based one proposed by my professor.

Comment: You can drop the `-MF $(@:.o=.d)` part as it is automatically done by `-MMD`.